# npm install fails when package is a dependency

Tags: git, node.js, makefile, npm

I am building an npm package (`libsbmlsim`) that installs binaries that I will later be using server side.

The package builds just fine when I run `npm install`, however, when I use it as a dependency in a different project via `npm install libsbmlsim`, it fails to find one of the binaries that it depends on (`cmake`):

```
/bin/sh: ../../node_modules/cmake/bin/cmake: No such file or directory                                                                                                                                      
make: *** [all] Error 127                                                                                                                                                                                   
npm ERR! libsbmlsim@0.0.2 install: `make`                                                                                                                                                                   
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 2                                                                                                                                                                     
npm ERR!                                                                                                                                                                                                    
npm ERR! Failed at the libsbmlsim@0.0.2 install script.
```

I suspect it has to do with my setup, so I will explain it a bit here. `libsbmlsim` depends on a few other binaries (`cmake` and `libsbml`), that I also have as bundled as npm packages which I bring in as dependencies or `npm install cmake` etc. I set the install script in the package.json files of each package to run `make`, and I have a corresponding `Makefile` that downloads the binaries.

Again, this works when I run `npm install` when I have `libsbmlsim` as its own project but it fails to install when it is installed as a dependency, i.e. `npm install libsbmlsim`.

Here is my Makefile:

```
all:
    wget http://fun.bio.keio.ac.jp/software/libsbmlsim/downloads/libsbmlsim-1.1.0.tar.gz
    tar -xvzf libsbmlsim-1.1.0.tar.gz
    mkdir -p libsbmlsim-1.1.0/build
    cd libsbmlsim-1.1.0/build; export PATH=../../node_modules/cmake/bin:$(PATH); cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=../../libsbmlsim -DLIBSBML_INCLUDE_DIR=../../node_modules/libsbml/include -DLIBSBML_LIBRARY=../../node_modules/libsbml/lib64/libsbml.so
    cd libsbmlsim-1.1.0/build; export PATH=../../node_modules/cmake/bin:$(PATH); make -j4
    cd libsbmlsim-1.1.0/build; make install;
    rm -rf libsbmlsim-1.1.0
    rm *.tar.gz
```

Source is available here: https://github.com/stanley-gu/libsbmlsim

Comment: what do you mean by "fails to install correctly"?  What the error message.

Comment: I added the error message and some more detail, I rely on a binary in a different package, I call `node_modules/cmake/bin/cmake`, which works fine when I run `npm install` normally, but when it is being installed as package from the npm registry, where I set the install script as `make`, it fails to find the binary, even though I have added it as a dependency.

Comment: based on the error, it can not find the cmake binary.  Since I can't run here, is cmake available when building where you think it is?

Comment: That is where I am stumped on, so when I am building my package, in the libsbmlsim repo, I can run npm install on itself, which downloads the cmake binary as a dependency, and then calls the binary within `node_modules` to build itself. The problem though is when I want to use libsbmlsim as a dependency, npm install fails to find the cmake binary even though it is listed in the dependencies.

Comment: Not sure if it will be helpful, but I have the project here: https://c9.io/stanley-gu/libsbmlsim2

Comment: not really, getting a directory listing of the node_modules directory when you install as a dependency would.  or at least check that cmake is present inside the node_modules of your module, which should be something like node_modules/libsbmlsim-1.1.0/node_modules/cmake/bin/cmake

Answer (score 1):

Unless you've published your module to the npm registry (`npm publish`), you'd need to look at `npm link` during development.

more details http://howtonode.org/introduction-to-npm (somewhat sparse)

Comment: Thanks for you response, I did indeed publish it to the npm registry, which is how I tried to consume it as a dependency in a second application.

Comment: you can't really use a redhat package inside your npm.  Doesn't work on mac for example.  why can't you rely on plain make?  because the lib you are using needs cmake?

Comment: I do know it's not a good idea to include a binary inside the package, but I have a few different applications that require cmake to build, and I was hoping to have a solution so that I can easily get the cmake binaries and build with npm.